# Excel vba Create combinations in same row each one

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a macro that exports all combinations of a range in same row each one ( I mean horizontal exports).

Every combination I want to be in one cell each time.

I want to change any time the number of strings in the range and also the number of strings combinations (In the example below 4 strings in the range and 3 for combinations)

```
1. A B  C  D     -------------ABC --ABD--ACD--BCD
 2. E F  G  H--------------EFG---EFH--EGH--FGH
 3. I G  K  L----------------IGK----IGL---IKL---GKL
```

Below its a module that I found in web that is very close to what I need.

I am very new to Vba macros and I cannot achieve what I am looking for with the below code

```
Private NextRow As Long

Sub Test()
Dim V() As Variant, SetSize As Integer, i As Integer

    SetSize = Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim V(1 To SetSize)

    For i = 1 To SetSize
        V(i) = Cells(2, i).Value
    Next i

    NextRow = 4
    CreateCombinations V, 3, 3

End Sub


Sub CreateCombinations( _
                   OriginalSet() As Variant, _
                  MinSubset As Integer, MaxSubset As Integer)

Dim SubSet() As Variant, SubSetIndex As Long
Dim SubSetCount As Integer, Bit As Integer
Dim k As Integer, hBit As Integer
Dim MaxIndex As Long

hBit = UBound(OriginalSet) - 1
ReDim SubSet(1 To UBound(OriginalSet))

    MaxIndex = 2 ^ UBound(OriginalSet) - 1
    For SubSetIndex = 1 To MaxIndex
        SubSetCount = BitCount(SubSetIndex)
        If SubSetCount >= MinSubset And SubSetCount <= MaxSubset Then
            k = 1
            For Bit = 0 To hBit
                If 2 ^ Bit And SubSetIndex Then
                    SubSet(k) = OriginalSet(Bit + 1)
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next Bit
            DoSomethingWith SubSet, SubSetCount
        End If
    Next SubSetIndex
End Sub


Sub DoSomethingWith(SubSet() As Variant, ItemCount As Integer)
Dim i As Integer


    For i = 1 To ItemCount
        Cells(NextRow, i) = SubSet(i)
    Next i
    NextRow = NextRow + 1
End Sub





Function BitCount(ByVal Pattern As Long) As Integer
    BitCount = 0
    While Pattern
        If Pattern And 1 Then BitCount = BitCount + 1
        Pattern = Int(Pattern / 2)
    Wend
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. What did you try?

Comment: Thanks Arno, I was tried the module that i found in web.As new in Vba i cannot make my own changes.

Comment: Can you format your sample data to be easier to understand? Is `ABCD` all in one cell? are they separated by spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the reply mehow . In my initial range every string is in one cell .Not ABCD all in one cell.So ,They dont separated by spaces .

Comment: But every combination id like to be in one cell.Example ABC all of these in one cell , ABD all of these in the next cell of the row .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

In your excel sheet, add an array formula like this:

```
     A     B     C     D    E
 1   
 2   A     B     C     D    {=k_combinations(CONCATENATE(A2;B2;C2;D2);3)}
 3   E     F     G     H    {=k_combinations(CONCATENATE(A3;B3;C3;D3);3)}
```

Note that you should extend the array formula to columns F, G, H and so on so that you get all results. (The `{` and `}` are not to be inserted manually, they are the mark of the array formula) :

1. Select cells E2, F2, G2, H2, and so on to Z2
2. Type the formula
3. To validate input, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Put the following code into a code module.

```
Public Function k_combinations(ByVal chLetters As String, ByVal k As Long) As Variant
 Dim chCombinations() As String
 Dim uCount As Long
 Dim vReturn() As Variant
 Dim i As Long

 uCount = Get_k_combinations(chLetters, chCombinations, k)

 ReDim vReturn(0 To uCount - 1) As Variant

 For i = 0 To uCount - 1
  vReturn(i) = chCombinations(i)
 Next i

 k_combinations = vReturn

End Function

Private Function Get_k_combinations(chLetters As String, chCombinations() As String, ByVal k As Long) As Long

 Dim i As Long
 Dim M As Long
 M = Len(chLetters)

 If k > 1 Then

  Get_k_combinations = 0
  For i = 1 To M - (k - 1)
   Dim chLetter As String
   Dim uNewCombinations As Long
   Dim chSubCombinations() As String
   Dim j As Long
   chLetter = Mid$(chLetters, i, 1)
   uNewCombinations = Get_k_combinations(Right$(chLetters, M - i), chSubCombinations, k - 1)
   ReDim Preserve chCombinations(0 To Get_k_combinations + uNewCombinations) As String
   For j = 0 To uNewCombinations - 1
    chCombinations(Get_k_combinations + j) = chLetter & chSubCombinations(j)
   Next j
   Get_k_combinations = Get_k_combinations + uNewCombinations
  Next i

 Else

  ReDim chCombinations(0 To M - 1) As String
  For i = 1 To M
   chCombinations(i - 1) = Mid$(chLetters, i, 1)
  Next i
  Get_k_combinations = M

 End If

End Function
```

`Get_k_combinations` is called recursively. The performance of this method is quite poor (because it uses string arrays and makes a lot of reallocations). If you consider bigger data sets, you will have to optimize it.

Comment: Hi d-stroyer.Thanks a lot for your answer .I just try this but there is a problem .In the export of this function there is no Queue of the letters. Example:for the 4 set of letters ABCD one combination of 3 is ACD .Your fuction gives me CDA that i don't want it .Is there a way that i can fix it?

Comment: Also when i choose, for the 4 set of letters ABCD the combinations of 2 letters (i change to {=k_combinations(CONCATENATE(A2;B2;C2;D2);2)}) that gives me only four combs and repeat the sames.It should be returns six different combinations . Thanks again for your kind answer .

Comment: This is not a problem of the code. You entered a formula in E2 an then exended it to F2, ... meaning that you have a different formula in F2 than in E2. As said in my post, you have to write it as an *array formula* !

Comment: Of course this is not code problem.The problem was mine because i didn't see your 3 help steps .This really works now .Thanks a lot man .

Comment: Happy that it works. Actually I added the 3 help after your last comment. This excel feature is not the most user-friendly. By the way, if you like my answer, please `accept` it.

Comment: Of course i already accept it .One thing more .If i have in my initial range these strings A1 B9 C8 D5 in 4 different cells. Is it a way to calculate as 4 strings and not as 8 ? I mean to create combinations for the 4 cells ? The strings in One cell to be one object for cominations

Comment: Sure it is possible. One would have to rewrite the interface to take arguments as an array of strings (probably as an excel Range object), and change the items aggregation method.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand.Is it a macro procedure?