# How to find which value creates maximum combination - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations, vba

I need to find which value creates the maximum combination shown below in Excel Vba

suppose,
I have combinations like this

```
a   a+b a+b+c   1   1+2 1+2+1   3   4
b   a+c a+b+d   2   1+1 1+2+3   2   6
c   a+d a+b+e   1   1+3 1+2+2   4   5
d   a+e a+c+d   3   1+2 1+1+3   3   5
e   b+c a+c+e   2   2+1 1+1+2   3   4
    b+d a+d+e       2+3 1+3+2   5   6
    b+e b+c+d       2+2 2+1+3   4   6
    c+d b+c+e       1+3 2+1+2   4   5
    c+e b+d+e       1+2 2+3+2   3   7
    d+e c+d+e       3+2 1+3+2   5   6
```

I need to find which combinations creates maximum value, In this case the value "7" is maximum which is created by 2,3,2. Hence I want these value as a output in unique cells.
I may have thousands of combinations, hence i want these to be found automatically and to be output in unique cells automatically and run the program further.
Please help.

Thanks 
Balaji

Comment: Did you ttry `=CountIf()`?

Comment: What do you mean by `output b, c, d, to other cell`?  Like a string that consists of "b, c, d" or each individual value outputted to a unique cell?

Comment: Title says - Excel VBA, Post says Formula? Which one are you looking for? Also Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: You may want to see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377699/excel-vba-create-combinations-in-same-row-each-one/18380109#18380109) for listing combinations in VBA. Although, I think the problem here is trivial an can be solved by mere sorting.

Comment: Thank you for your replies
@d-stroyer 
a,b,c,d,e are numbers, i want these numbers to be output to a unique cell

Comment: Thank you for your replies

@siddharth i didnt know the formula to that. if u can give me a formula it is well & good

Comment: For this function, a sum, answer is quite obvious: maximum individual values will result in maximum function result. So, your real question is how to find maximum values.

Comment: If there can be duplicates in a, b, c, d, e , there can be duplicate solutions as welll (a=3, b=3, c=3, d=2, e=1) --> a+b = 3, as well as a+c and b+c.

Comment: -1 because your question is not what you are requiring to answerers.

Answer (score 1):

**Concept :**

The greatest sum of m values within a set of n is the sum of the m bigger values.
Once the values are ordered in descending order, the solution is trivial.

Here is a pure Excel solution, without VBA.

**Design & Implementation :**

The user input (variable names and values) are in C4:D8.

The idea is the following:

1. Determine the order of data. For this, I use `RANK` in the column B.
2. Then use VLOOKUP in columns G and H to sort the data according to rank.
3. Then the maximum sums are trivial to compute in : sum of the n bigger numbers.

Here is the code:

```
     A                      B    C     D E    F                              G                              H I         J                                                      K
1                                            
2                           User input        Sorted by rank                                                            Maximum sums        
3    Rank                   name value   Rank name                           value                                      name                                                   value
4    =RANK.EQ(C4;$C$4:$C$8) a    45      1    =VLOOKUP(E4;$A$4:$C$8;2;FALSE) =VLOOKUP(E4;$A$4:$C$8;3;FALSE)   2 numbers =CONCATENATE($F$4;"+";$F$5)                            =$G$4+$G$5
5    =RANK.EQ(C5;$C$4:$C$8) b    1       2    =VLOOKUP(E5;$A$4:$C$8;2;FALSE) =VLOOKUP(E5;$A$4:$C$8;3;FALSE)   3 numbers =CONCATENATE($F$4;"+";$F$5;"+";$F$6)                   =$G$4+$G$5+$G$6
6    =RANK.EQ(C6;$C$4:$C$8) c    2       3    =VLOOKUP(E6;$A$4:$C$8;2;FALSE) =VLOOKUP(E6;$A$4:$C$8;3;FALSE)   4 numbers =CONCATENATE($F$4;"+";$F$5;"+";$F$6;"+";$F$7)          =$G$4+$G$5+$G$6+$G$7
7    =RANK.EQ(C7;$C$4:$C$8) d    12      4    =VLOOKUP(E7;$A$4:$C$8;2;FALSE) =VLOOKUP(E7;$A$4:$C$8;3;FALSE)   5 numbers =CONCATENATE($F$4;"+";$F$5;"+";$F$6;"+";$F$7;"+";$F$8) =$G$4+$G$5+$G$6+$G$7+$G$8
8    =RANK.EQ(C8;$C$4:$C$8) e    33      5    =VLOOKUP(E8;$A$4:$C$8;2;FALSE) =VLOOKUP(E8;$A$4:$C$8;3;FALSE)
```

Here is how the result looks:

```
     A       B    C     D  E   F    G    H    I            J          K
1                                            
2            User input        Sorted by rank              Maximum sums        
3    Rank    name value   Rank name value                  name       value
4    1       a    45      1    a    45        2 numbers    a+e        78
5    5       b    1       2    e    33        3 numbers    a+e+d      90
6    4       c    2       3    d    12        4 numbers    a+e+d+c    92
7    3       d    12      4    c    2         5 numbers    a+e+d+c+b  93
8    2       e    33      5    b    1
```

Note that it can be easily extended to more variables.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The example you have given works for different values in all the cells. If different cells have same values, this doesn't seems to work. I have rephrased my question, so u can understand better.

Comment: Well I spend 30 minutes creating the answer. Next time, please write your question completely in the first place.

Comment: There is indeed a solution with LARGE() function, which allows sorting the data in descending order with management of the duplicates. However, the associations value->name is not univocal I don't see how to write the string correctly. --> Using VBA is probably required.

Comment: I am sorry for wasting your time. But thanks a lot for taking your time to reply. This is my first post, hence didn't know how to explain it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on d-stroyer's answer, and converting it to VBA:

create UDF:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetMax(RNames As Range, RVals As Range, MaxNums As Long) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tmpName As String
Dim tmpVals As Long
Dim Names()
Dim Vals()

Names = RNames
Vals = RVals

For i = 1 To UBound(Names) - 1 'bubble sort
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Names)
        If Vals(i, 1) < Vals(j, 1) Then 'largest first
            tmpName = Names(i, 1)
            Names(i, 1) = Names(j, 1)
            Names(j, 1) = tmpName
            tmpVals = Vals(i, 1)
            Vals(i, 1) = Vals(j, 1)
            Vals(j, 1) = tmpVals
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To MaxNums
    If Vals(i, 1) <= 0 Then Exit For 
    'adding zero, or negative numbers will lower the total
Next i

For j = 1 To i - 1
    GetMax = GetMax & Names(j, 1) & ","
    'now we know how many values to use (from previous loop)
    'make the string up
Next j

If Len(GetMax) > 0 Then
    GetMax = Left(GetMax, Len(GetMax) - 1)
    'remove the final comma
Else
    GetMax = "No result found"
End If

End Function
```

Call using `=getmax(A1:A5,D1:D5,3)`
result would be **d,b,e**

I'll leave the rest up to you ov checking for error conditions, such as more than 1 column passed in the range, or ranges of unequal size, or a max # of items returned being larger than the range size